# How to solve 'list' object attribute 'sort' is read-only

Tags: python

I am trying to measure euclidean distance between test image and a given dataset. I have multiple values. Now I would like to sort them in ascending order but I am unable to do that. please help to solve this issue.
code:

```
    for j in range(50):

      f = sqrt(sum(j - test) ** 2)

      p = sorted(f, reverse= False)
```

some of output of f is:

```
    305753.0

    212825.0

    215385.0

    218201.0

    220761.0

    223833.0

    226905.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all the values in a list and sort it after the loop

```
values = []
for j in range(50):
    values.append(sqrt(sum(j - test) ** 2))
p = sorted(f)
```

With list comprehensions

```
values = [sqrt(sum(j - test) ** 2) for j in range(50)]
p = sorted(f)
```

Note that `reverse=False` is redundant.